# Cannot get response from AJAX in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I made a simple AJAX application, it worked fine for sometime, but I don't know what I did wrong with the app which does not run properly. I am putting all info here:

> This is HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 contact-wthree2">
        <h3 class="head2">Your Comments</h3>
        <form onsubmit="submit_form();">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 slideanim">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control first-name" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name"
                           required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 slideanim">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control last-name" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"
                           required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 slideanim">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control mail" id="mail" placeholder="Your Email" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 slideanim">
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control pno" id="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number"
                           required/>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-12 slideanim">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="message" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-12 slideanim">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline">Send Message</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="clickme" data-toggle="modal" data- target="#dialog" style="display:none">Open Dialog</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" id="response">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

> Then I wrote Javascript Code as follows:

```
<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


        var firstname =  document.getElementById('firstname').value,
        lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value,
        email = document.getElementById('mail').value,
        contact = document.getElementById('phone').value,
        message = document.getElementById('message').value;

    function submit_form()
    {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {

            if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200))
            {

                document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById('clickme').click();

                firstnameinp.value="";
                 lastnameinp.value="";
                 emailinp.value="";
                 contactinp.value="";
                 messageinp.value="";


            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open('POST','process_comments.php?firstname=' + firstname+'&lastname='+lastname
            +'&email='+email+'&contact='+contact+'&message='+message+'',true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }



</script>
```

> And here is my PHP file (process_comments.php):

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$firstname = "";
$lastname = "";
$email = "";
$contact = "";
$message = "";
$sql = "";
$table = "comments";
if (isset($_REQUEST['firstname']) && isset($_REQUEST['lastname']) &&    isset($_REQUEST['email']) && isset($_REQUEST['contact']) && isset($_REQUEST['message'])) {
//echo "Hi";
$firstname = "'" . $_REQUEST['firstname'] . "'";
$lastname = "'" . $_REQUEST['lastname'] . "'";
$email = "'" . $_REQUEST['email'] . "'";
$contact = $_REQUEST['contact'];
$message = "'" . $_REQUEST['message'] . "'";
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} VALUES (NULL,{$firstname},{$lastname},{$email},{$contact},{$message})";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {


    echo "<div class='alert alert-success' ><h4>Your message has successfully been sent.</h4></div>

        <div class=\"text-right\">
                    <button class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</button>

        </div>";
} else {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' ><h4> Message sending failed.</h4></div>

        <div class=\"text-right\">
                    <button class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</button>

        </div>";
}
} else {
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' ><h4>Message sending failed.</h4></div>

        <div class=\"text-right\">
                    <button class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-dismiss=\"modal\">Close</button>

        </div>";
}
```

This worked for some time, but now when I run this, it does not give the xmlhttp.responseText.
Anybody please help.

Comment: *"it does not give the desired result."* What is the desired result? What happens instead? Do you get any errors? What have you done to debug the issue? Is it a server side or a client side issue? Please read [ask].

Comment: I just don't get the _xmlhttp.resonseText_ which is the desired result.
I checked the google chrome's **'Develoer Tools'** where I don't have any error. I could get the _xmlhttp.responseText_ before, but now it is unavailable.

Comment: *"but now it is unavailable"* What does that mean? That he value is an empty string? Have you inspected the network requests made by the browser?

Comment: When I alert('hello') inside the if statement (if(xmlhttp.readyStatus==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)), it is alerted, but if I alert(http.responseText), that is not alerted. And the query does not insert any record in the database.

Comment: Click the network tab in your web inspector and look at the response from the server.

Comment: @mopsyd, I checked the web inspector where no XHR request is made by the bowser.

Comment: Wrap your `xmlhttp.open` and `xmlhttp.send` in a `try`/`catch` block, and `console.log` the error in the `catch` section.

Comment: Thank you all.
I switched to jQuery and the job is done.